# open a MVC4 view inside a jquery Dialog

Tags: dialog, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to take a view and instead of opening a new page I want to just open that view inside a Jquery dialog. I was just wondering how it's done or if possible.

HomeController.cs

```
      using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Jquery_Dialog.Models;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;

namespace Jquery_Dialog.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IEnumerable<Product> Products
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<Product>
                {
                  new Product {ProductID = 1, Name = "Train", Category = "Toy", Price = 29.99M},
                  new Product {ProductID = 2, Name = "Truck", Category = "Toy", Price = 19.99M},
                  new Product {ProductID = 3, Name = "Bread", Category = "Food", Price = 2.49M},
                  new Product {ProductID = 4, Name = "Cookies", Category = "Food", Price = 2.99M}
                };
            }
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            IEnumerable<Product> productList = Products;
            return View(productList);
        }

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            Product model = Products.Where(p => p.ProductID == id).SingleOrDefault();
            return Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? PartialView(model) : PartialView(model);
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Jquery_Dialog.Models.Product>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css " />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js "></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js "></script>


<table> @foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
  <td>
  @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Details", new { id = item.ProductID }, new { @class = "ajax-details" })
  </td>
</tr>
}
</table>

<div id="dialog" title="Title of dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.ajax-details').on('click', function (e) { // bind to click event
            // go get the page using the link's `href`
            $.get($(this).prop('href'), function (response) {
                $(response).dialog(); // take the response and throw it up in a dialog
                // optional: Use jQuery UI's options to specify buttons and other
                //           settings here as well. It's also probably a good idea to
                //           bind the close event and $().remove() this element from
                //           the page on close since the user can click links over and
                //           over. (prevent DOM overload of hidden elements)
            });
            e.preventDefault(); // don't let it continue on
        });
    });
</script>


<script>
        $("#dialog").dialog();
</script>
```

As you can see I have a simple dialog that opens a div but I want to be able to open the details view instead of clicking the ActionLink and going to a different page, I want to be able to click the ActionLink and have it open up in the dialog.

Comment: Long story short-- Have the action return a `PartialView`, then use an AJAX call to fetch that action's route and wrap it in a `$(...).dialog()` call.

Comment: @BradChristie I would love to do that.. if I knew how lol. I'm just beginning with MVC and web development so I'm trying to learn.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you make the `ActionLink` a little more accessible (by using a class name for instance):

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Details", new { id = item.ProductID },
  /* htmlAttributes: */ new { @class = "ajax-details" })
```

You also make a modification to the action so we can fetch partial contents when it's an ajax request:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
  // this is another way of making sure that AJAX calls get partial content,
  // but a normal visit would render the entire page.
  return Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? PartialView(model) : View(model);
}
```

***Optional** You could also adjust your `_ViewStart.cshtml` file to do the same if this was common place on the website to render partial views/ajax supplementing:*

```
@{
  Layout = IsAjax ? null : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Now, we wire it up with AJAX. Again, reference the class name we game the link earlier (`ajax-details`):

```
$('.ajax-details').on('click',function(e){ // bind to click event
  // go get the page using the link's `href`
  $.get($(this).prop('href'), function(response){
    $(response).dialog(); // take the response and throw it up in a dialog
    // optional: Use jQuery UI's options to specify buttons and other
    //           settings here as well. It's also probably a good idea to
    //           bind the close event and $().remove() this element from
    //           the page on close since the user can click links over and
    //           over. (prevent DOM overload of hidden elements)
  });
  e.preventDefault(); // don't let it continue on
});
```

Don't have the opportunity to test it, but should get you in the ball park. if it doesn't get you close enough, let me know and I'll revisit the answer and adjust.

Comment: return Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? PartialView(model) : View(model); is giving me an error so I just modified _ViewStart.cshtml. I added the Ajax code but nothing happens when I click the links.

Comment: @Claud25: Did you keep your original model building code and just modify the return? Also, make sure the javascript code is executed after page load (wrapped in `$(function(){ ... });`)

Comment: yes I did and it still doesn't work. When I click the actionLink, it doesn't do anything. No error, doesn't go to a partial page or nothing. It's like it wants to open a dialog but not working... I really don't know how to explain. I edited my question so you can see the code.